# HTML - Button element comes before table element which comes before text

Tags: html, element, block, display

I'm still learning HTML, the following snippet doesn't quite display as intended. Without making changes to the body element, how can I get the elements to display in the following block fashion...

Punnett square:

Monohybrid cross

table

button id="punnett_mono"

Dihybrid cross

table 5x5

button id="punnett_di"

Code snippet:

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    <p><b>Punnett square:</b></p>
    <u>Monohybrid cross</u>
    <p>
    <table style="width: 50%; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 25;">
    <tr>
    <td style="border: none; padding:30;"></td>
    <th colspan="2" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">Paternal:<br><div id="p_box" contenteditable></div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" style="border: 1 solid black;">Maternal:<br><div id="m_box" contenteditable></div></th>
    <td id="r2_c2" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="r2_c3" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="r3_c2" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="r3_c3" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    </tr>
    <input type="button" id="punnett_mono" onclick="p_mono p_box.innertext, m_box.innertext" value="Predict"/>
    </p>
    
    <u>Dihybrid cross</u>
    <p>
    <table style="width: 50%; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 25;">
    <tr>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
    </tr>
    <input type="button" id="punnett_di" onclick="p_di" value="Predict"/>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>

<body>
    <p><b>Punnett square:</b></p>
    <u>Monohybrid cross</u>
    <p>
        <table style="width: 50%; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 25;">
            <tr>
                <td style="border: none; padding:30;"></td>
                <th colspan="2" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">
                    Paternal:<br>
                    <div id="p_box" contenteditable></div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2" style="border: 1 solid black;">
                    Maternal:<br>
                    <div id="m_box" contenteditable></div>
                </th>
                <td id="r2_c2" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="r2_c3" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="r3_c2" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="r3_c3" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" id="punnett_mono" onclick="p_mono p_box.innertext, m_box.innertext" value="Predict" />
    </p>
    <u>Dihybrid cross</u>
    <p>

        <table style="width: 50%; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 25;">
            <tr>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
                <td id="" style="border: 1 solid black; padding: 30;">F1</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <input type="button" id="punnett_di" onclick="p_di" value="Predict" />
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

**You must close the table tag (:**

Answer (score 1):

Use `</table>` where the table ends

Comment: oops, my bad, rookie mistake, should have seen that though... very tired, anyway thanks guys!